# Fbx SDK up axis import issues

Tags: c++, opengl, 3dsmax, fbx

I have some problems when trying to import fbx files in a 3D application, using the Autodesk SDK.
When I'm exporting a mesh from 3ds Max and choose Y as the up axis in the exporter options, the vertices aren't transformed and the Z axis is still used as the up axis for the points coordinates in the file. This is expected, as I'm supposed to transform the scene to my defined axis system afterwards.
In the importer code, I'm veriyfing the axis system and I'm converting the scene to the one with Y as the up axis:

````
FbxAxisSystem axisSystem(FbxAxisSystem::eYAxis, FbxAxisSystem::eParityOdd, FbxAxisSystem::eRightHanded); ```
FbxAxisSystem sceneAxisSystem = fbxScene->GetGlobalSettings().GetAxisSystem();
if (sceneAxisSystem != axisSystem)
  axisSystem.ConvertScene(fbxScene);
````

However, the exported file already has the axis system similar with the one I'm using (the up axis is Y), so there is no convertion taking place.
If I export the same mesh from Blender or Maya, the axis system is the same too.
The only different attribute in the file exported from 3ds Max is the OriginalUpAxis attribute, which is 2 (Z), compared to 1, as it would be when exported from Maya.
I tried to export the mesh with Z as the up axis, the vertices are in the same positions as before, the scene conversion takes place this time (or at least the if statement fires), but when I'm trying to convert the vertices positions, I'm getting an identity matrix, which makes me believe that axisSystem.ConvertScene(fbxScene) does nothing:

```
FbxMesh *fbxMesh = meshNode->GetMesh();
FbxAMatrix& transform = meshNode->EvaluateGlobalTransform();
unsigned numFbxVertices = fbxMesh->GetControlPointsCount();
FbxVector4* lControlPoints = fbxMesh->GetControlPoints();

/*I'm getting an identity matrix here
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
*/
std::cout << transform.GetColumn(0).Buffer()[0] << transform.GetColumn(0).Buffer()[1] << transform.GetColumn(0).Buffer()[2] << transform.GetColumn(0).Buffer()[3] << std::endl;
std::cout << transform.GetColumn(1).Buffer()[0] << transform.GetColumn(1).Buffer()[1] << transform.GetColumn(1).Buffer()[2] << transform.GetColumn(1).Buffer()[3] << std::endl;
std::cout << transform.GetColumn(2).Buffer()[0] << transform.GetColumn(2).Buffer()[1] << transform.GetColumn(2).Buffer()[2] << transform.GetColumn(2).Buffer()[3] << std::endl;
std::cout << transform.GetColumn(3).Buffer()[0] << transform.GetColumn(3).Buffer()[1] << transform.GetColumn(3).Buffer()[2] << transform.GetColumn(3).Buffer()[3] << std::endl;
```

Is this an SDK bug? Any advice?

EDIT: It looks like node->ResetPivotSetAndConvertAnimation() for each node in the scene resets the transformation matrices too, that's why I was having this problem. Now it works perfect.

Comment: For future reference, could you answer your own question?